# multiply all values in particular columns if column name matches pattern

Tags: regex, r

I would like to make all values in certain columns negative (multiply by -1) if the column name matches a pattern.

My data:

```
df <- structure(list(forest_closed_start = c(3.87, 1.134, 0, 1.8, 2.43, 
40.752, 22.95, 9.432, 1.89, 1.53), forest_semi_closed_start = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), shrub_start = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), forest_closed_end = c(1.935, 0, 0, 1.8, 
2.43, 0, 22.95, 0, 0, 0), forest_semi_closed_end = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 8.1504, 0, 0, 0, 1.53), shrub_end = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("forest_closed_start", 
"forest_semi_closed_start", "shrub_start", "forest_closed_end", 
"forest_semi_closed_end", "shrub_end"))
```

Looks like:

```
> df
   forest_closed_start forest_semi_closed_start shrub_start forest_closed_end forest_semi_closed_end shrub_end
1                3.870                        0           0             1.935                 0.0000         0
2                1.134                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
3                0.000                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
4                1.800                        0           0             1.800                 0.0000         0
5                2.430                        0           0             2.430                 0.0000         0
6               40.752                        0           0             0.000                 8.1504         0
7               22.950                        0           0            22.950                 0.0000         0
8                9.432                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
9                1.890                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
10               1.530                        0           0             0.000                 1.5300         0
```

I would like to turn all columns that contain 'start' into negative numbers.

Thanks

-al

EDIT 1:

I would also like to create two new columns (`df$start` and `df$end`) which would be the sum of all columns that contain 'start' and 'end', respectively.

Comment: Turn all of them into negative numbers? Or multiply those columns by -1?

Comment: Sorry @Ananda Mahto, I shouldn't have mixed the two statements. I meant multiply by -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

or

```
df[,grep("start", names(df))] <- df[,grep("start", names(df))] * -1
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `edited` question

```
 within(df, {start <- rowSums(df[,grep("start", names(df))])
             end <- rowSums(df[,grep("end", names(df))])} )
```