# add columns together that match a pattern

Tags: regex, r

I would like to create two new columns, where one column (`df$start`) is the sum of all columns containing the phrase 'start' and the other column (`df$end`) is the sum of all columns containing the phrase 'end'.

My data...

```
df <- structure(list(forest_closed_start = c(3.87, 1.134, 0, 1.8, 2.43, 
40.752, 22.95, 9.432, 1.89, 1.53), forest_semi_closed_start = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), shrub_start = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), forest_closed_end = c(1.935, 0, 0, 1.8, 
2.43, 0, 22.95, 0, 0, 0), forest_semi_closed_end = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 8.1504, 0, 0, 0, 1.53), shrub_end = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("forest_closed_start", 
"forest_semi_closed_start", "shrub_start", "forest_closed_end", 
"forest_semi_closed_end", "shrub_end"))
```

Looks like...

```
> df
   forest_closed_start forest_semi_closed_start shrub_start forest_closed_end forest_semi_closed_end shrub_end
1                3.870                        0           0             1.935                 0.0000         0
2                1.134                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
3                0.000                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
4                1.800                        0           0             1.800                 0.0000         0
5                2.430                        0           0             2.430                 0.0000         0
6               40.752                        0           0             0.000                 8.1504         0
7               22.950                        0           0            22.950                 0.0000         0
8                9.432                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
9                1.890                        0           0             0.000                 0.0000         0
10               1.530                        0           0             0.000                 1.5300         0
```

Comment: Just edit your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385689/multiply-all-values-in-particular-columns-if-column-name-matches-pattern) instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know what would be more appropriate. Will edit prior question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `grepl` and `rowSums` can help

```
ind <- grepl("start", names(df))
df$start <- rowSums(df[,ind])
df$end <- rowSums(df[,!ind])
```